# Call a variable from function and display in text field oop php

Tags: php, html, oop, function, variables

i want to show user specific data in html form(in text fields or in select list)

I have a function ShowUserInformation() in class MyClass:

```
function ShowUserInformation()
{
    $query = "SELECT id, name, email FROM saloni WHERE id = '$_SESSION[ID_korisnika]'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
        $id= $row['id'];
        $name= $row['name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $address= $row['address'];
        $address2= $row['address2'];
        $address3= $row['address3'];
    endwhile;   

    return $result;
}
```

My question is: How can i display value of $name, or $email, $id... on another page in text box or in select list?

If i do it in procedural way it works when i do this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name ?>" name="name" class="" />
```

But, how can i display the $name,$email,$ID... in oop way? Is there a way to call it directly and not declare it as class variable and then call it.
i've included file, created object...

```
$my_class = new MyClass; //create an object of class
```

HTML - i've tried something like this...

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $my_class->ShowUserInformation($name)?>" name="name" class="" />
```

I'm new in PHP and oop so be easy with me :)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only plan on one row being returned, then why not use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
class MyClass{
    public function GetUserInformation(){
        $query = "SELECT id, name, email FROM saloni WHERE id = '$_SESSION[ID_korisnika]'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $info;
    } 
}

$class = new MyClass;
$info = $class->GetUserInformation();?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $info['id']?>" name="id" class="" />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $info['name']?>" name="name" class="" />
```

**Note:** mysql_* functions are deprecated, and you should move to use MySQLi or PDO

Answer (score 1):

First, change the function to get the data:

```
function ShowUserInformation()
{
    // Assuming you need only one user, I have set "LIMIT" to "1"
    $query = "SELECT id, name, email, address, address2, address3 FROM saloni WHERE id = '$_SESSION[ID_korisnika]' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    return mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

Now, get the information:

```
$my_class = new MyClass;
$userData = $my_class->ShowUserInformation();

// HTML
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $userData['name']; ?>" name="name" class="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

kindly try this:

```
<?php  
$show_info=ShowUserInformation();  

$data = $show_info->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
foreach($data as $row){ ?>
<input type="text" value="<?php  $row['name']; ?>" name="name" class="" />
<?php } ?>
```

OR

```
<?php $show_info=ShowUserInformation();  
while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($show_info){ ?>
<input type="text" value="<?php  $row['name']; ?>" name="name" class="" />
<?php } ?>
```